# Looping through a dictionary using a generator in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to loop on a dictionary to find all the possible combinations, to be more specific, if I input {'a' : [1,2], 'b' : 3}, I want to get {'a' : 1, 'b' : 3} and {'a' : 2, 'b' : 3}.

I tried to write a generator that would work recursively :

```
def loop_dic(dic, head={}):

    if len(dic) == 0:
        yield head

    k = dic.keys()[0]
    vals = dic[k]
    dic.pop(k)
    if not hasattr(vals, '__iter__'):
        vals = [vals]

    for v in vals:
        _head = head.copy()
        _head.update({k:v})
        loop_dic(dic, _head)
```

but it doesn't work, as it gets a GeneratorExit: None at the first recursive call.
How to do this?

Comment: Did you remember to `yield from`?

Comment: I never used 'yield from', also I use Python 2.7

Comment: This will also destructively modify `dic` so that it's empty by the time the generator is exhausted.  Is that really what you want?  It's very abnormal for a generator to destroy the object it's iterating over.

Comment: I modified the code, copying the dictionary object before popping the first element. it works now, but still a bunch of lines of codes

Comment: You shouldn't need to `pop` at all.  Why not just iterate over the keys, without modifying it?

Comment: How do you simply iterate over the keys to achieve this result?

Answer (score 2):

All you did is call `loop_dic()`; you didn't do anything with it.  In Python 3, you can just do:

```
        yield from loop_dic(dic, _head)
```

In Python 2, you need a loop:

```
        for item in loop_dic(dic, _head):
            yield item
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now, after adding a `_dic= dic.copy()` and a `return` after the `yield head`.